# Print content in-between matched patterns, but only for the first match

Tags: sed

I have an `output` file containing thousands of lines of information. Every so often I find in the output file information of the following form¨

```
Input Orientation:
...
content
...
Distance matrix (angstroms):
```

I now want to print the `content` and save to `filename`. However, the above occurs at several places in the output file, and I only want the last entry in the output file. Here's what I've tried so far

```
tac output | sed -n -e '/Distance matrix/,/Input orientation/p' > filename
```

However, this prints prints all instances of the matched pattern to `filename`.

Then I read that with GNU sed, of which I have version 4.2.1 installed, the following should work:

```
tac output | sed -n -e '0,/Distance matrix/,/Input orientation/p' > filename
```

But this gives me an error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unknown command: `,'
```

Then I tried to ask sed to quit after matching pattern `Input orientation`:

```
tac output | sed -n -e '/Distance matrix/,/Input orientation/{p;q}' > filename
```

But now it   ends up only printing `Distance matrix (angstroms):` to `filename`

I'm sure it if possible, I'm just not able figure it out! I have no experience with awk, so I would prefer answers using sed.

Sample output file for testing:

```
Item               Value     Threshold  Converged?
             Maximum Force            0.005032     0.000450     NO
             RMS     Force            0.001066     0.000300     NO
             Maximum Displacement     0.027438     0.001800     NO
             RMS     Displacement     0.007282     0.001200     NO
             Predicted change in Energy=-8.909077D-05
             GradGradGradGradGradGradGradGradGradGradGradGradGradGradGradGradGradGrad

                                      Input orientation:
             ---------------------------------------------------------------------
             Center     Atomic      Atomic             Coordinates (Angstroms)
             Number     Number       Type             X           Y           Z
             ---------------------------------------------------------------------
                  1          6           0        Incorrect    Incorrect    Incorrect
                  2          1           0        Incorrect    Incorrect    Incorrect
                  3          1           0        Incorrect    Incorrect    Incorrect
                  4          1           0        Incorrect    Incorrect    Incorrect
                  5         17           0        Incorrect    Incorrect    Incorrect
                  6          9           0        Incorrect    Incorrect    Incorrect
             ---------------------------------------------------------------------
                                Distance matrix (angstroms):
                                1          2          3          4          5
                 1  C    0.000000
                 2  H    1.080163   0.000000
                 3  H    1.080326   1.809416   0.000000
                 4  H    1.080621   1.810236   1.810685   0.000000
                 5  Cl   1.962171   2.470702   2.468769   2.465270   0.000000
                 6  F    2.390537   2.343910   2.357275   2.380515   4.352568
                                6
                 6  F    0.000000

                                          Input orientation:
                 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
                 Center     Atomic      Atomic             Coordinates (Angstroms)
                 Number     Number       Type             X           Y           Z
                 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
                      1          6           0        Correct    Correct     Correct
                      2          1           0        Correct    Correct     Correct
                      3          1           0        Correct    Correct     Correct
                      4          1           0        Correct    Correct     Correct
                      5         17           0        Correct    Correct     Correct
                      6          9           0        Correct    Correct     Correct
                 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
                                    Distance matrix (angstroms):
                                    1          2          3          4          5
                     1  C    0.000000
                     2  H    1.080516   0.000000
                     3  H    1.080587   1.801890   0.000000
                     4  H    1.080473   1.801427   1.801478   0.000000
                     5  Cl   1.936014   2.458132   2.459437   2.460630   0.000000
                     6  F    2.414588   2.368281   2.365651   2.355690   4.350586
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because, `sed` would quit as soon as it sees `q`. You need to qualify it again

```
$ tac ip.txt | sed -n '/Distance matrix/,/Input orientation/{p;/Input orientation/q}' | tac
                                          Input orientation:
                 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
                 Center     Atomic      Atomic             Coordinates (Angstroms)
                 Number     Number       Type             X           Y           Z
                 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
                      1          6           0        Correct    Correct     Correct
                      2          1           0        Correct    Correct     Correct
                      3          1           0        Correct    Correct     Correct
                      4          1           0        Correct    Correct     Correct
                      5         17           0        Correct    Correct     Correct
                      6          9           0        Correct    Correct     Correct
                 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
                                    Distance matrix (angstroms):
```

With `awk`

```
tac ip.txt | awk '/Distance matrix/{f=1} f; /Input orientation/{exit}' | tac
```

See also: [How to select lines between two patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with sed whithout tac

```
sed ':B;$x;/Input/!d;x;s/.*//;;x;:A;/Distance/!{N;bA};h;N;s/.*\n//;bB' infile
```

Keep the text in the holdspace and delete it when we find a new one.

Answer (score 0):

alternative `awk` without `tac`

```
$ awk '/Input orientation/ {f=1} 
                         f {a=a sep $0; sep=ORS} 
         /Distance matrix/ {f=0; b=a; a=sep=""} 
                       END {print b}' file
```

transfer and reset the cache after each end tag and print the last one.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/Input orientation/h;//!H;$!d;x;s/^\(Input orientation.*Distance matrix[^\n]*\).*/\1/p;d' file
```

At each occurrence of `Input orientation` overwrite the hold space (HS) with the current line, append following lines and delete all lines. At the end of the file, swap to the HS and remove lines following `Distance matrix` and print.

Alternative, along the same lines but perhaps less memory intensive:

```
sed '/Input orientation/h;//!{x;/./G;x};$!d;x;s/\(Distance matrix[^\n]*\).*/\1/p;d' file
```